# How to use movesense simulator?

Tags: visual-studio, movesense, whiteboard

I am new to visual studio... Can somenone tell me how to Use the movesense simulator I generated the CMake files and stored it in a folder....you can refer the documentation here(http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/).

cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../samples/jumpmeter_app

I ran this code on the terminal to generate the solution file....In the documentation this is written
"The cmake will generate the Visual Studio solution-file (Project.sln) in the build directory. Just open it with the Visual Studio IDE, select "Movesense" project as a "Startup project" and "Debug" it."

But when I run the solution file I don't see anything on the VS screen...It just starts the file and after I while I see ready on the bottom left corner...I want to do some PUT,DELETE commands on the sensor using the whiteboard API....How can I do that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b2P7.png)

Comment: Open Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio

Comment: Yeah I opened it @SamiKuhmonen I see some files how do I use it?